# Redirecionamento de url mantendo a url

Tags: redirecionamento, redirecionamento-de-url

Pessoal o meu cliente tem um plano de revenda na Locaweb onde ele tem um site principal e dentro deste pincipal tem os subsites que são gerados dinamicamente e não possuem pastas na hospedagem. Eu preciso redirecionar os dominios dos clientes dele para este sub-site da hospegem principal sem perder a URL original tem como fazer isto? Ex.

URL Pincipal: www.siteprincipal.com.br

Url sub-site: www.siteprincipal.com.br/cliente1

Url do cliente1: www.cliente1.com.br

Preciso redirecionar a Url do Cliente1 para a Url sub-site mas mantendo a URL do CLiente1 na barra de endereço.

O site dele foi feito em Laravel 5.1 com hospdagem Linux e PHP 5.6

Obrigado

Comment: Vc faz isso implementando "**hosts virtuais**". No Linux ubuntu isso é show. O servidor web(apache) no ubuntu vai abrir um site diferente(buscando numa determinada pasta) para cada url solicitada. :-)